# SoftKeyBoard is pushing whole layout upside

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

SoftKeyBoard is pushing whole layout upward including Titlebar. I have EditText at bottom of the screen and ListView is between title bar and EditText's RelativeLayout. I need only ListView should go upside not title bar. I used  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in **AndroidManifest.xml** but no success.
Below is my screens. Hoping you got my problem.

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

Here is xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topBarMusicDetailsEdit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/top_bar" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/TopBarText"
        android:text="@string/top_bar_text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/refreshButtonMusicDetails"
        style="@style/left_button_style"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/refresh_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backButtonMusicDetails"
        style="@style/right_button_style"
        android:src="@drawable/back_but"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/detailToggleLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30.0dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topBarMusicDetailsEdit"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/text_bar" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
        android:text="Messaging"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/grayline"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/detailToggleLayout"
    android:background="#808080" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chatList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/enterMsgLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/grayline"
    android:cacheColorHint="@null"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:stackFromBottom="false"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
     >
</ListView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/enterMsgLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="44.0dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editChat"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendChat_img"
        android:background="@drawable/textfield_multiline_activated_holo_dark"
        android:hint="  Enter Message"
        android:paddingLeft="7.0dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </EditText>
    <!-- "@drawable/blue_text_bar" -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sendChat_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5.0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_chat_msg" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout.xml file please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustResize` of your activity in the `Manifest`

```
<activity android:name="com.package.YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your manifest file Activity declaration as follows, hope will work.

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateUnchanged|adjustResize"
```